# Cant generate a download link for a file that exists in virtual directory in azure using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

i have a container which consists of many virtual directories for example :
https://accountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/blobName , and the blob name is a virtual directory on azure let's say for example : number/name/UUID/anotherUUID/file.txt and iam trying to download the file.txt but each time i get the following error :
`BlobNotFound`
although i can generate the download link using sas token from azure portal and get a download link for the file and it is downloaded succesfully , but when i generate the download link from inside my spring boot application i get the error above .

here is the code for uploading a blob :

```
    BlobClient blob = container.getBlobClient(filePath); // where file path is the virutal directory path
     blob.upload(BinaryData.fromBytes(bytes));

and here is the code for downloading the blob :

 BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(container name)
          .getBlobClient(filepath);

      OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now()
                                                .plusDays(1);
      BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
      BlobServiceSasSignatureValues values = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission).setStartTime(
          OffsetDateTime.now());
      String sasToken = blobClient.generateSas(values);

      String fileUrl = blobClient.getBlobUrl();
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(fileUrl);
      stringBuilder.append("?");
      String last = stringBuilder.toString();
      String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(last, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

      return result+sasToken;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written.

Comment: okay i will post it write now

Comment: plase check the code above @Guarav Mantri

Comment: Can you share the SAS URL? Please obfuscate the account name and sig portion in your SAS URL before sharing.

Comment: https://accountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/subDircetoty1/subDircetoty2/subDircetoty3/filename?sv=2021-12-02&st=2023-03-12T10%3A50%3A20Z&se=2023-03-13T10%3A50%3A15Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=sig , that's the generated url

Comment: Thanks! Your SAS Token looks ok to me. What happens when you copy the SAS URL and paste it in a browser? Do you still get 404 error?

Comment: yes !!  should the container be public ? although when the path is containerName/fileName it downloads normally .

Comment: No, the container need not be public (in fact, it **should not** be public unless really needed). I am wondering if there's something special in your virtual directory name considering everything works if the blob is put directly beneath a container.

Comment: can the subDirectory name be a uuid or not ?

Comment: Sure, it can be. no issues with that.

Comment: is there any special configuration to be done from azure portal side ?

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment using below code and got expected results. Check if it helps you to fix the issue and achieve your requirement.

- *Be sure that your container has the required privileges*.

Here, I'm using the post mapping to upload the file via REST API call.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        String str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<your_account_name>;AccountKey=<your_account_key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
        BlobSasPermission permission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
        BlobServiceSasSignatureValues values = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, permission)
                .setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClientBuilder().connectionString(str)
                .containerName("<your_container_name>").buildClient();

        BlobClient blob = container.getBlobClient("ParentDir/"+"ChildDir/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
        blob.upload(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize(), true);
        String sasToken = blob.generateSas(values);

        String  result  = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(blob.getBlobUrl()  +  "?",  StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

     return result +  sasToken;
}
```

**Update:**

when calling the BlobClient class, if we pass the filename as parameter in the `container.getBlobClient()`, it will create file inside the container.
To create file inside the directory, we have to pass directory with `/` along with the filename inside the `container.getBlobClient()` as shown below:

```java
BlobClient blob = container.getBlobClient("ParentDir/"+"ChildDir/"+file.getOriginalFilename());
```

[image]

[image]

**Updated Output:**

I could download the file with the generated URL as shown below:

[image]

Comment: actually i did this and it is working becauce the file is directly in the container but if it is for example pravuworkitem/subDirectory1/subDirectory2/text.json it will not work as expected

Comment: I have checked with the filepath also and it is working fine. Please check the updated answer and the code provided.

Comment: Okay so what i understood that while downloading i will get the blob client with path and the file name and when downloading i pass the path and the file name too !! Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: done accepting the answer thanks for your help @PravallikaKV